How do I create a per user xkb keymap?
It is possible to create your own custom xkb maps by adding files to /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols. However, this directory is managed my dpkg and requires root access. Is there a way of placing a keymap under somewhere $HOME where setxkbmap file find it?
Question closed on SO as not about programming: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79204214/how-do-i-create-a-per-user-xkb-keymap

The man page mentions -config but I got parse errors when I used this.

This documentation page mentions $HOME/.xkb/ along with some other paths but this didn't seem to work with setxkbmap

Both xkbcomp and setxkbmap have a -I option to select custom directories.
setxkbmap -I"$HOME/.xkb" -types complete+foo

will combine types/complete from the system XKB installation with the file ~/.xkb/types/foo.
Libxkbcommon reads ~/.xkb by default, but despite the name, not all XKB tools use that library. In fact, the basic X11 tools do not use that library — it's only used by newer projects that are trying to replace X11.
